# Python3 Сайт 127.0.0.1 отправил недействительный ответ

Tags: python, python-3.x, tcp, python-3.6

Когда только начал изучать `python socket` . То сразу же написал свой tcp сервер по аналогам другим. Мой старый код, который все время работал на `python 3.4.4`, сейчас же у меня установлен `python 3.6.1` . 
Ошибка:

```
Страница недоступна

Сайт 127.0.0.1 отправил недействительный ответ.
ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE
```

**Код из старого проекта https://github.com/Danchick1337/Punch-Network:**

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#* Import all the necessary modules and continuation of the code
from time import gmtime, strftime
import socket, requests
import sys, os, time
support_thread = False #*thread not support
main_file = 'punch-network.py' #main-file not other file 'main'
def tcp_server(): #server code socket
        try:
                global data, getHost, getPort, os, buffer, timed, full, clear
                os = 'windows' ; os_linux_machine = 'unix'
                true_status = 200 ; false_status = 404 
                buffer = 1024 ; timed = strftime("%Y:%H:%M:%S", gmtime()) ; clear = 'cls'
                getHost = '127.0.0.1' ; getPort = int(sys.argv[1]) ; start = sys.argv[2]
                full = (getHost, getPort)
                if start == '-run_server':

                        print(' Punch-Network Started at '+'['+timed+']\r')
                        print('     -- Punch-Network Log --\r\n')

                        try:
                                punch = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
                                punch.bind(full) ; punch.listen(5)

                                while True:
                                        conn, full = punch.accept()
                                        data = conn.recv(buffer)
                                        if not data:
                                                only_data_error = True 
                                                if only_data_error:
                                                        print('error')
                                        #handling module
                                        else:

                                                conn.sendall(b"""
                                                        <html>
                                                        <head>
                                                        <title>Punch-Network</title>
                                                        </head>
                                                        <body>
                                                        <h3>Punch-Network Version 0.BETA Worked!</h3>
                                                        </body>
                                                        </html>
                                                """)
                                pass
                                punch.close()
                        except socket.herror as herr:
                                print('error')
                        except socket.timeout as terr:
                                print('error')
                        except socket.gaierror as gerr:
                                print('error')
                else:
                        print('Error options, true-options: punch-network.py port -run_server')


tcp_server()
```

Убрал все лишние модули.  Самый обычный tcp-сервер только с измененным интерфейсом. Раньше все работало, заходил на `127.0.0.1:порт` и у меня уже высвечивалось что все работает. Теперь же не сервер, не клиент не работают.

Comment: Если не работает сервер, то укажите ошибку? Как у вас работает клиент без сервера? Мало информации для того чтобы помочь Вам.

Comment: @ Dmitry Erohin убрал клиент, клиент к серверу вообще не относится, я к нему не подключаюсь просто пытаюсь уместить 2 ошибки в 1 вопрос.

Comment: Ошибку вы получаете в браузере?

Comment: @Dmitry Erohin  да.

Comment: Так вы неправильно готовите ответ клиенту. Ошибка в вызове `conn.sendall` добавьте заголовок для браузера.

Comment: @Dmitry Erohin  можете пожалуйста добавить это в ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Перед отправкой содержимого страницы для корректной обработки браузером необходимо добавить заголовок, примерно такого содержания:

`conn.send(b"HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n")`

а ниже вызов функции conn.sendall(...)

Comment: Спасибо! Действительно заработало!